# List items disapear after I append in list

Tags: python, list, append

I simplify the list for better understanding.
I have a list that dynamicly change (let say):

```
recPkt = [10, 1, 38, 64]
```

And want to check if list match with some list inside a list (like the one bellow). This List of lists is read from txt file.

```
mDdata = [[10, 1, 37, 6], '|', [10, 1, 37, 64], '|', [10, 1, 37, 45], '|', [10, 1, 37, 51]]
```

If list is not inside I want to append it to list of lists (mDdata).

My problem is that when I append. The updated list is not saved correctly. It is eather all lists inside list are the same, only last list is diffrent or  the empty lists gets appended (depending where I put `pcktLst [:] = []` )

```
if isDev == 1: #device is on list
    devdata = []
    devdata [:] = []
    pcktLst = []
    pcktLst [:] = []
    ind = myReadList.index(devAddr+"-END"+"--------------------------------------------")
    devdata = myReadList [iJ + 10: ind] 
    devdata = str(devdata)
    x = devdata.find("(")
    y = devdata.find(")")

    devdata = devdata[(x+1):(y)]
    devdata = devdata.split('|')

    mDdata = []
    mDdata [:] = []
    s = 0
    devLst = []
    devLst [:] = []
    dd = readDtoL(devdata) #returns list of list of existing data in txt file

    count = 0


    for eaItm in dd:
        eaItm = eaItm.replace("[","")
        eaItm = eaItm.replace("]","")
        eaItm = eaItm.split(", ")

        pcktLst [:] = []
        print eaItm
        print dd
        for eaNumb in eaItm:
            print  eaNumb
            eaNumb = int(eaNumb)
            pcktLst.append(eaNumb)

        devLst =  pcktLst
        if count == 0 :
            mDdata.append(devLst)
            print mDdata

        elif count > 0:
            mDdata.append("|")
            mDdata.append(devLst)
            print "Count"
            print mDdata
        count+=1
        pcktLst [:] = []

    bla = []
    bla [:] = []
    for eNumb in recPkt:
        #print  eNumb
        eNumb = int(eNumb)
        bla.append(eNumb)

    print bla
    #print mDdata
    if (bla in mDdata) == False:
        mDdata.append("|")
        mDdata.append(bla)
    print "TOLE JE PO APPEND"
    print mDdata
```

My best guess  is that I should have some temp. variable or change list to tuple.

Comment: Sounds like your code would be simpler if you used a `set` of tuples rather than a list of lists - this would automatically prevent duplicate entries

Comment: It seems like this code could be much smaller and more readable. Can you paste an example file that you'd be reading from, and your desired output?

Comment: `for eNumb in recPkt:` ... I don't see `recPkt` anywhere? Did I miss it?

Comment: `pcktLst [:] = []` creates empty list... when you append empty list, well, you get empty list appended - isn't that the problem?

Comment: There's no need for all the `some_list = []; some_list[:] = []`. Just do `some_list = []`.

Comment: recPkt is given in func argument

Comment: You have a lot of places where you're assigning a list to a variable, then mutating it later, when I think you intend for a copy to be assigned to that variable.

Comment: @alphiii, can you describe what you're trying to accomplish with this code? Do so as if you want someone else to write an entire script to do it themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the advise about some_list =[].

Comment: I want to accomplish that when I recieve a packet (list of ints), i need to check if this is already inside, if not append it and write it to txt

Comment: do your sub-list have same length? perhaps there is a better way to do this.

Comment: yes sub-list have same lenght , only I append laso this string ( "|") to seperate  sub-lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the part which is causing your issue is -

```
devLst =  pcktLst
if count == 0 :
    mDdata.append(devLst)
    print mDdata

elif count > 0:
    mDdata.append("|")
    mDdata.append(devLst)
    print "Count"
    print mDdata
count+=1
pcktLst [:] = []
```

When you do -

```
devLst = pcktLst
```

You are just assigning the reference of `pcktLst` to `devLst`, they both refer to the same list. And when you do - `mDdata.append(devLst)` - you are appending that list reference inside the list `mDdata`.

Then when you do -

```
pcktLst [:] = []
```

This inplace clears the list referenced by `pcktLst` , which is also the list `devLst` as well as the lsit you just appended to `mDdata` . You should not be doing that . A very short Example to show this behavior -

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = a
>>> c = []
>>> c.append(a)
>>> c
[[1, 2]]
>>> b
[1, 2]
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> a[:] = []
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[]
>>> c
[[]]
```

I am guessing you have some kind of wrong understanding of `[:]` , when the slicing is used on the left side of assignment operator, you are asking python to mutate the list inplace, this would reflect in all names which *refer* to the list. You should use this unless you really need to mutate inplace, and I do not see any need for that. You can just do -

```
pcktLst = []
```

This would cause `pcktList` point to a new list, without causing any issues to the list that it previously pointed to. You should use it like this everywhere.

---

Also, when you do -

```
mDdata = []
mDdata [:] = []
s = 0
devLst = []
devLst [:] = []
```

This does not do any benefit, you can just write -

```
mDdata = []
s = 0
devLst = []
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation,will check

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`all`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) function and with the [**`symmetric_difference (^)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference) method to check if your list contains exactly the same elements with any sub-list in `mDdata`.

```
>>> if all(set(recPkt) ^ set(el) for el in mDdata if isinstance(el, list)):
...     mDdata.append('|')
...     mDdata.append(recPkt)
... 
>>> mDdata
[[10, 1, 37, 6], '|', [10, 1, 37, 64], '|', [10, 1, 37, 45], '|', [10, 1, 37, 51], '|', [10, 1, 38, 64]]
```

Comment: @alphiii glad to have been of help!